# Not able to connect python with hive on windows machine

Tags: python, hive, package

I have installed anaconda navigator and working in the spyder workbook. 
I am getting an error like TTransport exception. 
I have installed all the packages like pyhive, sasl, thrift, thrift-sasl. while connecting python to hive, I was getting this error,"Could not start SASL: b'Error in sasl_client_start (-4) SASL(-4): no mechanism available: Unable to find a callback: 2'". 
Is there any packages do I want to install?? As well I am working in windows, so kindly help me with that..

from pyhive import hive
import sasl
import thrift
import thrift_sasl
conn1 = hive.Connection(host="xxxxx", port=00000, username="yyyy")

## cur2 = conn1.cursor()

Errors:
conn1 = hive.Connection(host="xxxx", port=00000, username="yyyy")
Traceback (most recent call last):

File "", line 1, in 
    conn1 = hive.Connection(host="xxxx", port=00000, username="yyyy")

File "C:\Users\sgpbtp02\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pyhive\hive.py", line 192, in **init**
    self._transport.open()

File "C:\Users\sgpbtp02\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\thrift_sasl__init__.py", line 79, in open
    message=("Could not start SASL: %s" % self.sasl.getError()))

TTransportException: Could not start SASL: b'Error in sasl_client_start (-4) SASL(-4): no mechanism available: Unable to find a callback: 2'